# python3 a==c, b==d, a==b, but c is not equal to d, please help me to understand why

Tags: python-3.x, variables, equality

I created a recursive function that can reverse the order of a linked list. For example, if a linked list is originally [3,2,1], the function will return [1,2,3].

Below is the code:

```
class node:
   def __init__(self,val,next=None):
      self.val=val
      self.next=next  

def recursive(l3):
    if l3.next is None:
        return l3
    else:
        a=l3           
        head=recursive(l3.next)
        b=head       
        while b.next is not None:
            b=b.next
        b.next=a
        b.next.next=None
        return head
```

Now I have a linked list `a` :

```
a=node(1,node(2))
```

However when i tried `recursive(a)==recursive(a)` it returns false. How come the two are not equal when I am essentially comparing one to itself. Could you help me to understand why the two are not the same variable?

Thank you

Comment: This isn't a [MCVE]; please provide one. Otherwise, there's no way to tell how your `node` class is implemented, and it could hide all manner of errors.

Comment: If this is not caused by mutable state, then the issue can be summarized as: Equality is not transitive (identity is). That means if a==b and b==c, that doesn't necessarily mean that a==c.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I have provided the code for node class, hope it helps to better understand my overall code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is indeed mutability. You need to consider what `recursive` does to your linked list. Apart from returning a "reversed linked list", it mutates the original. It happens e.g. here:

```
a=l3           
...
b.next=a
b.next.next=None
```

Effectively, this is the same as doing `l3.next = None`.

Most importantly, though, two linked lists you constructed share the same node, `c`, and it is also mutated by calling `recursive` (its `next` is reassigned).

Indeed, after calling `recursive(a)` you can see that `c.next` is pointing to `node(2)` instead of `None`. After calling `recursive(b)` `c.next` points to `node(4)` instead.

For this reason, `recursive` returns `node(1)` if you call it on `a` **or** `b`, but if you call it on `a` and *then* on `b`, it returns `node(1)` and then `node(2)`.

---

Edit: you changed the question to only use one variable, which makes it even more obvious: the problem is that each call mutates the argument.